# A word to describe a prolific scientist, inventor or explorer who was inspirational and innovative

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What are some nouns with which we would refer to a scientist, inventor or explorer who was inspirational and innovative. To think of an analogy: *biscuits* are cheap,while *cookies* are expensive. Similarly, are there words that refer to a glorious scientist/innovator?

This question does not have a unique answer, so feel free to include words that you think you would use in such circumstances.

Comment: I've never heard value given as the distinguishing factor between biscuits and cookies; what do you mean by that analogy?

Comment: "To think of an analog: biscuits are cheap,while cookies are expensive." Yes - this is odd to my ears, plus it should be "analogy", not analog.

Comment: Changed it to analogy? I thought even analog was correct, but probably the context was not right.

Comment: I was under the impression that the richer cousin of biscuits were cookies. Thanks for pointing out that it is not universally factual.

Comment: On behalf of all lovers of *rich tea biscuits*, *hobnobs*, and *chocolate digestive biscuits* the world over, I protest at their being tarnished as being *cheap*. they may cost less than some of your fancier cookies, but they are as good, (and some as fattening) as their American counterparts! :P

Comment: "A modern-day Edison."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Luminary**

(can also be used sarcastically)

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/luminary?s=t

**Maestro**

(nearly impossible to use sarcastically)

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/maestro?s=t

Answer (score 0):

Luminary or genius are probably the closest in the context.

Comment: This post would be improved by explaining *why* you suggest these terms, for example, by providing a dictionary definition or examples in the wild. I encourage you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

A **seminal**/**distinguished** scientist/investor, etc.

Comment: I am not looking for adjectives, but nouns. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Not a noun, but consider *groundbreaking:*

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/groundbreaking)

Definition 3.
originating or pioneering a new endeavor, field of inquiry, or the like:
Pasteur's groundbreaking work in bacteriology.

Edit: *Groundbreaker* is a noun

Answer (score 0):

Consider, ***trailblazer***.

> : an innovative leader in a field; a pioneer. [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trailblazer)

As for a word that refers to a glorious scientist or innovator, how about ***father***?

> : a person who has originated or established something. [Random House](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/father)